# Issue with PHP fopen(), file_get_contents(), cURL()

Tags: php, api, curl, fopen, file-get-contents

Im trying to connect to a web service, when I connect to it using a form, explicitly declaring the URL in form `action="{{ URL of web service }} + parameters"`, Im able to connect and use the web service. However when I use `fopen()`, `file_get_contents()` or cURL I get authentication error.

I have already tried declaring the username and password(username:password) in `fopen()` and doing it also in cURL and using the different authentication method in cURL(basic etc). and still no luck.

I really would love to have an explanation for this behavior.

Comment: Can you please add a code example?

Comment: Have you checked with the providers of the service?

Comment: When making requests programmatically the trick is to mimick the exact request you make from your browser. So including all headers etc..

Comment: Hi guys thank you for the fast responses. If I copy paste the URL setting with the parameters that I use in fopen(), file_get_contents() and cURL() in my browser, it works. I tried using both GET and POST still no luck.

Comment: Thank you also for asking for code examples. I am sure its not about any syntax error or missed out semicolons. I already tried to use the same set of codes on a different web service url and fopen(), file_get_contents(), cURL() works.